# Overload resolution failed with extension method overload

Tags: .net, extension-methods, overloading

In my project I have a Helper class StringHelper which contains an String.Replace overload that accepts a StringComparison parameter.
I use this method elsewhere in the same project.

This compiles fine the first time, every consecutive build after that however gives the error

```
'Overload resolution failed because with extension method overload'
```

This can be resolved by deleting my bin folder. Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project's Reference list.
It might contain a reference to itself, thus compiling your extension method twice and resulting in the said double overload.

To solve: remove reference to self.

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/94f920e6-7015-4879-95d7-a460da309ae1
Added for myself so I will find this answer in the future.